How is my question not focused? I think it is focused
Someone closed my question for not being focused. The help page says:

Needs more focus - If your question has many valid answers (but no way
to determine which, if any, are correct), then it probably needs to be
more focused to be successful in our format.
This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should
focus on one problem only.
This can often be fixed by breaking the post into multiple questions,
or by focusing on a specific part of the problem.

I would like someone to please explain to me why is this question considered not focused? I think it is focused because it is asking to solve exactly one problem. The people who closed the question didn't write any comments to help me improve the question or provide any justification. I put a lot of effort in writing the question and framing it according to the rules of the site as I understood them.
Is it because I split the main question into 4 parts according to priority? I think that only helps to write a better answer. In my experience, a good answer to questions like this will already include the answers to the sub-questions I have put.
Is it because this is a problem that is too general to answer? To me, this is a specific problem that I want to solve as soon as possible. It is very specific to this web application (WhatsApp Web) on this browser (Google Chrome). In case it's a bug in WhatsApp Web or Chrome, I would expect to know the work-around in the answer. In case I am doing some mistake while using WhatsApp Web, I would like to know about it so I can avoid it.
Does this question fall into a particular category of questions that are discouraged? I can't see it from my limited experience with Web Applications site, but please let me know if it is so.
If there is any other reason this question is considered not on focus, please let me know.
